# Generate a report of mismatch Columns between 2 Pyspark dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Team, we have a requirement to generate a report of mismatched columns based on key field between 2 Pyspark dataframes of exactly same structure.

Here is first dataframe-

```
>>> df.show()
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|     key|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    abcd| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc| def| qew| uvw|
|   abcd1| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc| def| qew| uvw|
|  abcd12| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc| def| qew| uvw|
| abcd123| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc| def| qew| uvw|
|abcd1234| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc| def| qew| uvw|
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

And here is 2nd dataframe-

```
>>> df1.show()
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|     key|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    abcd| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc| def| qew| uvw|
|   abcdx| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc| def| qew| uvw|
|  abcd12| 123| xyz|   a| abx| abc|defg| qew| uvw|
| abcd123| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc|defg| qew| uvw|
|abcd1234| 123| xyz|   a|  ab|abcd|defg| qew| uvw|
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Full Outer Join gives me this-

```
>>> dfFull=df.join(df1,'key','outer')
>>> dfFull.show()
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|     key|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  abcd12| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc| def| qew| uvw| 123| xyz|   a| abx| abc|defg| qew| uvw|
|   abcd1| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc| def| qew| uvw|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|
|abcd1234| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc| def| qew| uvw| 123| xyz|   a|  ab|abcd|defg| qew| uvw|
| abcd123| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc| def| qew| uvw| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc|defg| qew| uvw|
|   abcdx|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc| def| qew| uvw|
|    abcd| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc| def| qew| uvw| 123| xyz|   a|  ab| abc| def| qew| uvw|
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

if i just look at col6, there are 5 values which mismatched for the "key" field (only value match is for last record).

```
>>> dfFull.select('key',df['col6'],df1['col6']).show()
+--------+----+----+
|     key|col6|col6|
+--------+----+----+
|  abcd12| def|defg|
|   abcd1| def|null|
|abcd1234| def|defg|
| abcd123| def|defg|
|   abcdx|null| def|
|    abcd| def| def|
+--------+----+----+
```

I need to generate a report of something like this for all the columns. The mismatch sample can be any record's value from dataframes.

```
colName,NumofMismatch,mismatchSampleFromDf,misMatchSamplefromDf1
col6,5,def,defg
col7,2,null,qew
col8,2,null,uvw
col5,3,null,abc
```

It is a column wise summary based on key, saying how many values are mismatch between 2 dataframes.

Sid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the two dataframes are *df1* and *df2*, you can try the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, array, count, first

# list of columns to be compared
cols = df1.columns[1:]

df_new = (df1.join(df2, "key", "outer")
    .select([ when(~df1[c].eqNullSafe(df2[c]), array(df1[c], df2[c])).alias(c) for c in cols ])
    .selectExpr('stack({},{}) as (colName, mismatch)'.format(len(cols), ','.join('"{0}",`{0}`'.format(c) for c in cols)))
    .filter('mismatch is not NULL'))

df_new.show(10)
+-------+-----------+                                                           
|colName|   mismatch|
+-------+-----------+
|   col4|  [ab, abx]|
|   col6|[def, defg]|
|   col6|[def, defg]|
|   col5|[abc, abcd]|
|   col6|[def, defg]|
|   col1|    [, 123]|
|   col2|    [, xyz]|
|   col3|      [, a]|
|   col4|     [, ab]|
|   col5|    [, abc]|
+-------+-----------+
```

**Notes:** (1) the condition `~df1[c].eqNullSafe(df2[c])` used to find the mismatches satisfies either of the following:

```
+ df1[c] != df2[c]
+ df1[c] is NULL or df2[c] is NULL but not both
```

(2) The mismatches if exist are saved as *ArrayType* column with the first item from *df1* and 2nd item from *df2*. NULL is returned if no mismatch and later filtered out.

(3) the *stack()* function dynamically generated by Python format functions is as follows:

```
stack(8,"col1",`col1`,"col2",`col2`,"col3",`col3`,"col4",`col4`,"col5",`col5`,"col6",`col6`,"col7",`col7`,"col8",`col8`) as (colName, mismatch)
```

After we have df_new, then we can do the groupby + aggregation:

```
df_new.groupby('colName') \
    .agg(count('mismatch').alias('NumOfMismatch'), first('mismatch').alias('mismatch')) \
    .selectExpr('colName', 'NumOfMismatch', 'mismatch[0] as misMatchFromdf1', 'mismatch[1] as misMatchFromdf2')
    .show()
+-------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|colName|NumOfMismatch|misMatchFromdf1|misMatchFromdf2|
+-------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|   col8|            2|           null|            uvw|
|   col3|            2|           null|              a|
|   col4|            3|             ab|            abx|
|   col1|            2|           null|            123|
|   col6|            5|            def|           defg|
|   col5|            3|            abc|           abcd|
|   col2|            2|           null|            xyz|
|   col7|            2|           null|            qew|
+-------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```