# Column based comparison between two tables in different databases using pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have two databases in Snowflake, DB1 & DB2. the data is migrated from DB1 to DB2, so the schema and the table names are the same.

Assume DB1.SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1 has this data:

```
STATE_ID    STATE
1               AL
2               AN
3               AZ
4               AR
5               CA
6               AD
7               PN
8               AP
9               JH
10              TX
12              LA
```

and

Assume DB2.SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1 has this data:

```
STATE_ID    STATE
1               AL
2               AK
3               AZ
4               AR
5               AC
6               AD
7               GP
8               AP
9               JH
10              HA
```

They both have one more column 'record_created_timestamp' but I drop it in the code.
I wrote a pyspark script that would perform Column based comparison that would run in Aws Glue job. I got help from this link: [Generate a report of mismatch Columns between 2 Pyspark dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59620636/generate-a-report-of-mismatch-columns-between-2-pyspark-dataframes)

My code is :

```
import sys

from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, col, lit, to_timestamp, when
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
import os
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, count, first

import json
import datetime
import time

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

now = datetime.datetime.now()


year = now.strftime("%Y")
month = now.strftime("%m")

day = now.strftime("%d")

glueClient = boto3.client('glue')
ssmClient = boto3.client('ssm')

region = os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']
SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'CONNECTION_INFO', 'TABLE_NAME', 'BUCKET_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)

client = boto3.client("secretsmanager", region_name="us-east-1")

get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
        SecretId=args['CONNECTION_INFO']
)

secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
secret = json.loads(secret)

db_username = secret.get('db_username')
db_password = secret.get('db_password')
db_warehouse = secret.get('db_warehouse')
db_url = secret.get('db_url')
db_account = secret.get('db_account')
db_name = secret.get('db_name')
db_schema = secret.get('db_schema')


logger = glueContext.get_logger()
logger.info('Fetching configuration.')

job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)


java_import(spark._jvm, SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)

spark._jvm.net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeConnectorUtils.enablePushdownSession(spark._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate())
sfOptions = {
"sfURL" : db_url,
"sfAccount" : db_account,
"sfUser" : db_username,
"sfPassword" : db_password,
"sfSchema" : db_schema,
"sfDatabase" : db_name,
"sfWarehouse" : db_warehouse
}

print(f'database: {db_name}')
print(f'db_warehouse: {db_warehouse}')
print(f'db_schema: {db_schema}')
print(f'db_account: {db_account}')


table_name = args['TABLE_NAME']
bucket_name = args['BUCKET_NAME']



MySql_1 = f"""
              select * from DB1.SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1

"""

df = spark.read.format("snowflake").options(**sfOptions).option("query", MySql_1).load()
df1 = df.drop('record_created_timestamp')



MySql_2 = f"""
              select * from DB2.SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1
               
"""

df2 = spark.read.format("snowflake").options(**sfOptions).option("query", MySql_2).load() 
df3 = df.drop('record_created_timestamp')





# list of columns to be compared
cols = df1.columns[1:]

df_new = (df1.join(df3, "state_id", "outer")
    .select([ when(~df1[c].eqNullSafe(df3[c]), array(df1[c], df3[c])).alias(c) for c in cols ])
    .selectExpr('stack({},{}) as (Column_Name, mismatch)'.format(len(cols), ','.join('"{0}",`{0}`'.format(c) for c in cols)))
    .filter('mismatch is not NULL'))



df_newv1 = df_new.selectExpr('Column_Name', 'mismatch[0] as Mismatch_In_DB1_Table', 'mismatch[1] as Mismatch_In_DB2_Table')

df_newv1.show()


SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "snowflake"



job.commit()
```

This provides me the correct output:

```
Column_Name   Mismatch_In_DB1_Table   Mismatch_In_DB2_Table
   STATE           AN                             AK
   STATE           CA                             AC
   STATE           PN                             GP
   STATE           TX                             HA
```

If I use STATE instead of STATE_ID to outer join

```
df_new = (df1.join(df2, "state", "outer")
```

It shows this error.

```
AnalysisException: 'Resolved attribute(s) STATE#1,STATE#9 missing from STATE#14,STATE_ID#0,STATE_ID#8 in operator !Project [CASE WHEN NOT (STATE#1 <=> STATE#9) THEN array(STATE#1, STATE#9) END AS STATE#18]. Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: STATE,STATE. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;;\n!Project [CASE WHEN NOT (STATE#1 <=> STATE#9) THEN array(STATE#1, STATE#9) END AS STATE#18]\n+- Project [coalesce(STATE#1, STATE#9) AS STATE#14, STATE_ID#0, STATE_ID#8]\n +- Join FullOuter, (STATE#1 = STATE#9)\n :- Project [STATE_ID#0, STATE#1]\n : +- Relation[STATE_ID#0,STATE#1,RECORD_CREATED_TIMESTAMP#2] SnowflakeRelation\n +- Relation[STATE_ID#8,STATE#9] SnowflakeRelation\n
```

I would appreciate an explanation regarding this and want to know if there is a way this could run even if I give STATE as the key.
or
If there is some other code via which I can get the same output without this error, that would help too.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Spark is getting confused with the column names of both dfs. Try to give alias to them to make sure they match:

```
df1 = df.drop('record_created_timestamp')\
        .select(df.STATE_ID.alias('state_id'), df.STATE.alias('state'))
        
df3 = df.drop('record_created_timestamp')\
        .select(df.STATE_ID.alias('state_id'), df.STATE.alias('state'))
```

Also, make sure '''STATE_ID''' has no space/special charachters in this column's name

Comment: @LuizVoila I tried the alias. It gives an error:
```
AnalysisException: 'Resolved attribute(s) STATE_ID#0,STATE#1 missing from STATE_ID#12,STATE#13 in operator !Project [STATE_ID#0 AS state_id#18, STATE#1 AS state#19]. Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: STATE_ID,STATE. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;;\n!Project [STATE_ID#0 AS state_id#18, STATE#1 AS state#19]\n+- Relation[STATE_ID#12,STATE#13] SnowflakeRelation\n'
```

Comment: @LuizVoila  I tried to outer join it using "state" and "state_id" and it was a success. I think the problem lies somewhere in

` ` `
cols = df1.columns[1:]

df_new = (df1.join(df3, "state_id", "outer")
    .select([ when(~df1[c].eqNullSafe(df3[c]), array(df1[c], df3[c])).alias(c) for c in cols ])
    .selectExpr('stack({},{}) as (Column_Name, mismatch)'.format(len(cols), ','.join('"{0}",`{0}`'.format(c) for c in cols)))
    .filter('mismatch is not NULL'))
` ` `